# MariaDB finding a soccer player that participated in all teams

Tags: mysql, mariadb

i'm trying to make a query in MariaDB that returns me the name of the player that played in all teams. I'm kind of new to queries, and havent had luck using inner join (mostly duing to not understanding it very well), and all the tries with IN didnt work out that well, ideias?

Edit: I'm not at my computer at the moment, so i don't have a specific example on the code but it's like

```
SELECT Soccer.player
FROM Soccer
WHERE Soccer.player in (SELECT * FROM Teams, TeamPlayers
WHERE Teams.tid = TeamPlayers.tid);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

**Example data**

```
create table soccer (player varchar(100));
insert into soccer values ('john'), ('matt'), ('katie');

create table teams (teamname varchar(100));
insert into teams values ('A'), ('B'), ('C');

create table teamplayers (team varchar(100), player varchar(100));
insert into teamplayers values
('A', 'katie'), ('B', 'katie'), ('C', 'katie'),
('B', 'john'), ('C', 'john'),
('C', 'matt');
```

**Expected result**

Since `katie` is the only player on all teams, we should print her name.

**Easier query**

```
select tp.player
from teamplayers tp
inner join teams t on t.teamname = tp.team
group by tp.player
having count(*) = (select count(*) from teams);
```

**Explanation**

- Join teamplayers and teams
- Group player (and find the count in `having` statement)
- If count matches the count of teams, select that player

**SQL Fiddle**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7110b/15

**Query**

This query can be written in different ways. I wrote it in a way that hopefully makes sense with inline explanation

```
select player
from soccer s
where not exists (

  select 1
  from

  -- get all possible combinations of team and players
  (select player, teamname from soccer, teams) main

  -- combine the above with team players
  left join teamplayers tp
    on tp.team = main.teamname 
    and tp.player = main.player

  -- find those players who DO NOT end up in one or more teams
  -- and exclude those from select (see where NOT EXISTS)
  where tp.team is null
    and main.player = s.player

);
```

**Explanation**

- To know whether a person is on all teams, let's make a matrix of each player in all teams (the scenario where everybody is on all teams)
- Compare this scenario with teamplayers table. Those players NOT on one or more team will have NULL in `tp.team` field
- Compare all players with the above list and choose the ones who do NOT appear in that list

**Result**

katie

**SQLFiddle example**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7110b/11

Comment: This might take a while, first time i ever seem something w/o primary keys and what not. What does the main on combinations mean? Is it an alias? And what's the SELECT 1? I don't think i'll be able to use a null since that kind of comparison wasn't shown (It's a school work)

Comment: This is an example with 3 items. Primary key wasn't needed for an example. `main` is an alias for the subquery. `select <static-value>` or `select *` or `select <any-combination-of-fields>` can be used in a subquery with `where exists` and `where not exists`. I use `select 1`. The select isn't really doing much other than reporting whether there was a match or not so that `where not exists` can filter out appropriate data.

Comment: I've added an easier example that might help you, @stasisOo. It's added at the top. Look for `having count(*)` in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT store_type FROM stores s1
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM cities WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT * FROM cities_stores
       WHERE cities_stores.city = cities.city
       AND cities_stores.store_type = stores.store_type));
```

Found this example on a NOT EXISTS explanation site which worked out great! But thanks @zedfoxus, hope some day i do that stuff so easy

Comment: Good find. I've added an easier example also. Feel free to check that out. Please also mark either your own answer or mine as accepted to give closure to your question.